# Soft code Java class name

Tags: java

I have classes that provide static method to return data:

```
List<Object> list1 = Class1.getData();
List<Object> list2 = Class2.getData();
List<Object> list3 = Class3.getData();
...
```

Now at runtime I was given a class name 'Classn' and I need to get data from it. Can this be done? I wish I were able to do this (of course I cannot)

```
List<Object> list = "Classn".getData();
```

Is there a way to do this without using reflection?

Comment: No, this cannot be done without reflection. There might be a better way to design your application however, so that you don't need to do this. But without knowing anything about your application it's hard to say how.

Comment: If Class1,... Class3 all implement an interface - call it DataGetter with a method `List<Object> getData()` - it would be possible.

Comment: Thanks all for your answers. I need to re-design my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection makes the most sense, but I guess you could also use a switch statement:

```
switch (className) {
   case "Class1":
      return Class1.getData();
   case "Class2":
      return Class2.getData();
   .......
   case "Classn":
      return Classn.getData();
}
```

The reason why reflection makes the most sense is because otherwise, you would need a switch case for each individual classname, and that is not very good for scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Place your lists in a map, with class name as key, like this :

```
Map<String, List<Object>> classes = new HashMap<String, List<Object>>();
classes.put("Class1", Class1.getData());
...
```

and get the data based on the name :

```
List<Object> list = classes.get("Class1");
```